# script doesnt work syncronize with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using Ajax to show a specific form based on what option was selected in a select tag, but the alert in the `#send` action doesn't seem to work.

**script.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#SelectBox').on("change", function() {
        if ($('#SelectBox').val() == 'rectangle') {
            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url:'views/rectangle/index',
                data:{},
                success:(function (response) {
                    $('#Container').html(response);
                })
            })
        $('#send').click(function () {
            alert("clicking");
        })
        }else if($('#SelectBox').val() == 'square'){
            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url:'views/square/index',
                data:{},
                success:(function (response) {
                    $('#Container').html(response);
                })
            })
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: put your click outside of SelectBox on change.

Comment: you mean you want to bind the click event to the response DOM that you retrieve from the `$.ajax`?